# I knew I would enjoy the music. or I knew I should enjoy the music

Tags: modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

> I knew I would enjoy the music.

> I knew I should enjoy the music.

Is there any difference between them?

My dictionary says 'should' is used in BrE in case of I or We though 'would' is used in AmE all the time regardless of the person.

Comment: You have posted many questions recently asking the difference between two sentences with no indication of what you already understand about them, nor showing that you've made any effort to find answers yourself. You should only ask a question here after you've tried to answer it yourself. This is not a tutoring service. Please [edit] this question to meet the standards of this site or I'll start closing them

Comment: @gotube Thanks for your comment and I undertand what you mean but it's kind of hard for me to articulate the question due to cultural and personal difference in terms of language and efficiency of learning.

Comment: It's unfortunate, but there's a certain level of English ability required to ask questions at this site. In my opinion, your English skills are certainly high enough to form proper questions. Even if it's inefficient for you to write proper questions, it's not OK to reduce the efficiency of people answering questions by making us ask you for lots of necessary details in the comments before they can even be answered.

Comment: What dictionary are you using?  It may be time to invest in a better one...

Comment: It's not like merriam or oxford or the like but it's at least good for some reference. There are another two examples: You could do it, if you would. I just want to ask you one question, if it wouldn’t bother you.

Comment: Your dictionary is mistaken, or you didn't read the entry carefully enough. "Should" is used in both dialects for every subject, singular and plural.

Comment: I'd still quite like to know what the dictionary **is** and not what it **isn't**. There are a lot of dictionaries, grammar books, text books etc in Asia that were written in the 1930s and not really updated since then *cough WrenandMartin cough*. They continue to teach a certain type of English that died out 100 years ago, and are often confused, and confusing about grammar.

Comment: @James K https://en.dict.naver.com/#/entry/enko/1a4610aeea464f68ab6c2a516f1a0a1c  (below pronunciation icons is there tab which shows dictionaries)

Comment: Please note "현대 영어에서는 전달문, 조건문, 요청을 나타내는 문장 등에 쓰이는 should와 would 사이의 전통적인 차이가 없어지고 should는 별로 쓰이지 않는다. ... 이제 should는 사람들에게 무엇을 해야 한다고 말할 때에나 충고를 할 때 또는 강조의 뜻을 덧붙일 때 주로 쓰인다:"    Which says pretty much the same as I say in my answer below.

Comment: Tranlated:  In modern English, the traditional distinction between should and would, which are used in conveyances, conditional sentences, and request sentences, etc., has disappeared and should is rarely used. ... Now should is used to tell people what to do or to give advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern British English,  "would" is acceptable and more common.  Using "should" would lead to potential confusion with the "ought to" sense of "should", and so ought to be avoided.

So in British English say "I knew I would enjoy the music", though you may (rarely, and in old-fashioned context) hear people saying "should" with the same meaning.

Usually if "should" is used, it means "I knew I ought to enjoy the music".

Comment: Your answer is great as I look back on it again.